# HTTPS BE with self sign certificate and HTTP Client interaction on localhost

Tags: reactjs, node.js, ssl, https, localhost

I'm using react as client FE and node js as server BE.

In the BE I'm using HTTPS protocol with self sign certificate (for development mode, in production I'm using certbot)

In the FE in production im using HTTPS so everything works well.
But in development i couldnt make a connection between my BE and FE on localhost.

I got Error: `"net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"`

** Using postman for making api calls to my BE works.

This is the app.ts in BE:

```
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors);

app.use(cookieParser());

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("./key.pem", "utf8");
const certificate = fs.readFileSync("./cert.pem", "utf8");
const credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpsServer.listen(ports.https, () => {
  console.log("https server is running at port with HTTPS PROTOCOL", ports.https);
});
```

Comment: *"But in development i couldnt make a connection between my BE and FE on localhost."* - and the exact error you get in the client is what?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks i forgot to mention the error :"net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"  . (already update in the original question)

Comment: Then you have the answer  - your client does not trust the issuer of the certificate. Which is pretty normal if you are using a self-signed certificate, because it is not issued by anything known to be trustworthy. In postman you likely just disabled certificate validation, so it ignores the problem.

Comment: yea i know that , i wounder how to let it work , what is the best practice when developing https ? to congif my react works on https even on dev mode on localhost?

Comment: There are various approaches - from creating a certificate for the local domain (self-signed) and importing it as trusted in the browser to using the external certificate for testing too by mapping the name to the local IP address.

Comment: didnt find any relevant guid, all what i did i faild. if u have some guidelines it can help

Comment: No idea what you tried to find - but the following search will provide many useful links - https://google.com/search?q=create+development+server+localhost+https+certificate